# react-datepicker accepting older dates those are disabled using minDate property

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker just like below having minDate property.

```
<DatePicker
  className="form-control"
  minDate={new Date()} 
  selected={this.props.GrantExpiryDate} 
  onChange={(e) => { this.props.onGrantExpiryDateSubmit(e); }} 
  disabled={disableControl} />
  {this.props.GrantExpiryDate == null ? <div className={styles.requiredValidation}>Please select a date</div> : ''}
```

If I select the Date by using DatePicker its worked fine as shown in the snap.

[image]

but when I entered date by manually typing in the date picker control it's allows me to enter older dates those are disabled.

[image]

I know this can be handled through the custom function but still this is not behavior which i was expecting from minDate property.

Is there any property or something to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  onChangeRaw={e => e.preventDefault()}
/>
```

Comment: Yes I did this but it's also blocking me to enter date manually in the form of text.

Comment: If you want to type date, what about try to handle compare in `onChnageRaw` function?

Comment: That's the my last choice to handle it by using custom function.If there is no other way to handle it.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think that's only way to you. `minDate` can prevent only selected not typing.

Comment: Oops! then i will go for custom function to prevent this problem. you may also add the function into your answer.

Comment: That's why I used to prevent typing date using `e.prevent()` just select.